# Create image with text like MEME image and save as a image file.Unable to save image while using Canvas to draw over Bitmap

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I'm creating an android app which basically merge a background image(default image) with user input via `EditText` in `xml` layout.
I have developed some of the working code but it seems like its not working properly.
Any kind of help is welcome.
P.S. new to development.

here is my `MainActivity.Java` class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

EditText editText; //defined edit text
Bitmap bmp; // defined Bitmap
Button button;

public void myBit(){

    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(editText.getDrawingCache());
}

public void saveImg()  {

    File myDir = new File("/sdcard/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdir();
    Random ran = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = ran.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-"+n+".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

        // canvas for merging text over image (Bitmap)
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); // Text Color
        paint.setStrokeWidth(12); // Text Size
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)); // Text Overlapping Pattern
        // some more settings...

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 400, 400, paint); // ◄ Edited here
        canvas.drawText("Testing...", 10, 10, paint);

        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

            saveImg();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
    return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: does the "sdcard/saved_images" folder exist? Did you declare the required permissions in your manifest file? Are you getting any exceptions with this code?

Comment: @GilMoshayof yes, i have declared all the permissions in manifest, and i' am not getting any exceptions with this code.

Comment: What about the folder? Does it exist? What value does mkdir() return?

Comment: @GilMoshayof Yes, the folder exists and it is creating an '0 bytes' image file, whenever the 'Save' button clicks.

Comment: Did you check the size of the bitmap you're creating via myBit()? Make sure it's size is greater than 0 (for width and height).

Comment: Its not generating bitmap with greater than 0 bytes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100878/discussion-between-jai-sharma-and-gil-moshayof).

Comment: @JaiSharma do you want to create image file from which will have edittext ? or you wants to create image file after drawing on canvas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Create file from bitmap on image below two way i have tried

- one by taking edittext as a image or passing view & get bitmap from the below posted code `getBitmapFromView`  method will convert view to bitmap
- second one is like give edittext text & draw on above the default
  image.`writeTextOnImage` this method will create bitmap from the given text above the image it will work like MEME type of image. give your image in place of `R.drawable.t_img`.

Activity

```
    public class CreateSaveImage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editText;
    private File file;
    Bitmap bmp; // defined Bitmap
    ImageView imgShowOuput;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_voice);
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "saveimage");
        file.mkdirs();
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTextView);
        imgShowOuput = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgShowOuput);
        findViewById(R.id.btnSaveImage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bmp = getBitmapFromView(editText);
                String path = file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_image" + ".jpg";
                saveBitmapToFile(bmp, path, 100);
                imgShowOuput.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                Toast.makeText(CreateSaveImage.this, "Image Saved!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.btnSaveImageFromText).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bmp = writeTextOnImage(CreateSaveImage.this, editText.getText().toString());
                String path = file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_drawImage" + ".jpg";
                saveBitmapToFile(bmp, path, 100);
                imgShowOuput.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * @param view
     * @return
     */
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        view.clearFocus();
        view.setPressed(false);
        view.setFocusable(false);
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }

    public static String saveBitmapToFile(
            Bitmap bitmap, String path, int quality) {
        File imageFile = new File(path);
        OutputStream os;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("BitmapToTempFile", "Error writing bitmap", e);
        }
        return imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    public Bitmap writeTextOnImage(Context mContext, String mText) {
        try {
            Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
            float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
            /// Here you need to give your default image
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.t_img);
            android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();
            if (bitmapConfig == null) {
                bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            }
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            // Change Text Size & Color based on your requirement
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize((int) (21 * scale));
            paint.setShadowLayer(20f, 0, 0, Color.LTGRAY);
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            paint.getTextBounds(mText, 0, mText.length(), bounds);
            // Change position based on your requirement
            int x = 20;
            int y = 20;
            canvas.drawText(mText, x * scale, y * scale, paint);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Xml Layuout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#7e95e6"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save EditText Image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveImageFromText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save Text from EditText as a Image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgShowOuput"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[Check output of above which i got](http://goo.gl/RyTsYe)

Let me know if anything..